# How to upload images to a sql database via php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an AdLister site - and so far everything a user posts into the database displays properly on the site except an image. Below is my code - Please let me know if I left anything out:

```
    $insert_table = "INSERT INTO posts (userid, post_date, title, price, description, email, location, image) VALUES (:userid, :post_date, :title, :price, :description, :email, :location, :image)";
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare($insert_table);
    $stmt->bindValue(':userid', 1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':post_date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':price', $price, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':image', $image, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();

    return $errors;
    }

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if (checkValues()) {

        $errors = insertPost($dbc);         
    } else {
        $message = "Invalid format. Please try again.";
        $javascript = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        echo $javascript;
    }
}

    if(Input::has('title')){
        if($_FILES) {
            $uploads_directory = '/img';
            $filename = $uploads_directory . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
                // echo '<p>The file '. basename( $_FILES['image']['name']). ' has been uploaded.</p>';
            } else {
                //alert("Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.");
            }
        }
       }
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr class='table-hover'>
            <th class="header">Photo</th>
            <th class="header col-md-1">Date Posted</th>
            <th class="header">Title</th>
            <th class="header col-md-1">Price</th>
            <th class="header col-md-6">Description</th>
            <th class="header col-md-6">Image</th>
        </tr>

            <?php
            foreach ($posts as $post):?>
                <tr class='table table-hover table-bordered body'>
                    <td>Photo</td>
                    <td><?= $post['post_date'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $post['title']?></td> 
                    <td><?= $post['price']?></td>
                    <td><?= $post['description']?></td>
                    <td><?= $post['image']?></td>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your trying to insert the image as a posted string value (like the other inputs) except data received from file inputs is stored as an array called $_FILES

So...

```
$_POST['image']
```

Will be empty but

```
$_FILES['image']['name']
```

Will contain the actual filename.

Rearrange your code to upload the file and get the name, then use that value to insert.

Oh and don't forget to include:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

on your html form tag!